# Python 3.8 - list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to return the names within a dict after combining two dicts into one (z):

```
z = {}
z['games'] = [yourdict2, yourdict3]
#print(z)
datalist = z['games']
for i in datalist:
        print(datalist[i]['name'])
```

But I am receiving a message stating: **list indices must be integers or slices, not dict**

Printing z and not datalist shows:

`{'games': [{'50': {'name': 'Half-Life: Opposing Force', rest of dict, etc }]`

I think this is because everything after ***{'games':*** is now a list, looking like:

`[{'50': {'name': 'Half-Life: Opposing Force', rest of dict, etc }]`

I'm not quite sure what I need to do now to print the name. I have combined the two dicts (yourdict2 and 3) this way instead of merging in order for them not to overwrite duplicate data (as I want to count the amount of times game name appears).

Any assistance would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, `i` is not an index, it is actually a `dict` object. You even have it: `{'50': {'name': 'Half-Life: Opposing Force', rest of dict, etc }`.

You'll need to iterate through the object's keys and values in order to print what you want:

```py
datalist = z['games']
for dlist in datalist:
    for key in dlist.keys():
        print(dlist[key]['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, the datalist is a list of dicts, therefor you need to either grab the values, or its keys to perform an action on like yours.

**Grabbing the keys**

```
z = {}
z['games'] = [yourdict2, yourdict3]
#print(z)
datalist = z['games']
for games in datalist:
    for game in games.keys():
        print(datalist[game]['name'])
```

Do you see? When you add `.keys()` in your loop, python will return the various game-keys.

**Grabbing the values directly**

```
z = {}
z['games'] = [yourdict2, yourdict3]
#print(z)
datalist = z['games']
for games in datalist:
    for game in games.values():
        print(game['name'])
```

Did you pick up on the difference?  When you call values() on a dict, you don't
need to reference the key anymore.  You can work straight from its value.

Answer (score 0):

you can change you code into this way:

```
z = {}
z['games'] = [{'50': {'name': 'Half-Life: Opposing Force' }}, 
              {'100': {'name': 'PUBG'}}]
games = [list_element[key]['name'] for list_element in z['games'] 
                                   for key in list_element]
print(games)
# output: ['Half-Life: Opposing Force', 'PUBG']
```

`list_element` is each element in the list `z['games']`, `key` is the key in every `list_element`, e.g. `'50'`, `'100'`.